# Import text from txt file into an URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, text

I was wondering if it is possible to have a text file (for example text.txt) with in that file only 1 word (for example: blue) so I can import this text into an URL on my HTML page.

```
<a src="localhost/img/TEXTFROMFILE.png"></a>
```

This way I can change the image by simply typing a word in the text file.
I guess you need to import the file and then create a string? But I am not an expert so..

Comment: yes you can do it, but why you need text file, instead you can define simple variable into js and access it.

Comment: $lines = file('myFile.txt'). your data in $lines .. and used where u want to used

Comment: Huh? I need to put that code as a script and how do I put it in the url?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that in Php, it would be easy.
I'm just showing you an example.

Let just say that the txt file is named blue.txt, than the code will be.

```
 <?php

    $name = file_get_contents("./blue.txt");
    echo "<a href=\"localhost/img/".$name.".png\"></a>";

?>
```

Here is the code for achieving it in client side.

Html + plain Javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/text.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var text = client.responseText;
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");        // Create a <a> element
  annchor.setAttribute("href", "localhost/img/"+text+".png");  
}
client.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am a real beginner, so I need to put that in as a script code? And than how can I put that into like an url?

Comment: That's just server side programming not client side

Comment: That code doesnt work for me, I changed the src to href but than it doesnt work

Comment: Do you run this with a Webserver?

Comment: Nope, just on local

Answer (score 1):

Note that "a"-tags have no "src" attribute.

Valid "a" attributes are listed here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Maybe you meant href instead of src ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, mistake